# Insert linebreak after every nth character in df column

Tags: python

I want to insert a linebreak (>br<), after every nth character for each cell in a df column. I have the following function, however don't know how to adjust it to iterate over every row of a df column, rather than just an individual text snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def insertNewlines(text, lineLength):
    if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    elif text[lineLength] != ' ':
        return insertNewlines(text[:], lineLength + 1)
    else:
        return text[:lineLength] + '<br>' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength + 1:], lineLength)
```

In response to user2906838:

My data is contained in a df called 'Messages', with the column in question being 'Message'. I tried your code, however it produces a syntax error for the line:

```
row[key] = return insertNewlines(text[:], lineLength + 1)
```

Sorry for not posting data earlier, please find a sample of my df here:

```
Excerpts:
Can this issue be closed?
The other precedences are OK; as far as I can tell... not worth messing around in the code for no demonstrable benefit.
we ran into this issue on our platform. it's possibly very specific to our setup; but the patch should cause no problems for any other setup as well. simplifying this into on line is of course possible. i can't really tell you any more about it; since this issue was fixed in our local implementation about one year ago by some colleague. in preparation for our migration to the current version of shindig and opensocial 0.9 i'm revising all patches and feature additions we did over the last year and will be looking at which are worth comitting. so you can expect some more small issues in the next weeks ;)
Completely non-related and probably belongs in another jira _x0089_Ã›Ã’ but I've added a small patch to fix two comment typos in HttpTransact (I know authorized can be spelt with an s _x0089_Ã›Ã’ but we don't do that anywhere else in the code)
Already fixed in UIMA-1379.
```

Comment: Have you tried `for row in df[foo]: row = insertNewLines(row, 5)`?

Comment: Try [`fmt`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fmt): `fmt --split-only --width=72 so.txt`

Comment: Unfortunatley pstatix that approach did not work. Can you clarify your comment @intentionally left blank, I've never used fmt so this code looks quite foreign to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've not shared any data, I will just consider `df` as your dataframe which has as many text columns as you want. Now to itirate over every row, you can simply use a `apply` function.

```
changedData = df["Messages"].apply(lambda row:insertNewlines(row), axis=1)
```

Now, in your `insertNewlines()` method, you can do whatever you want, you have the whole row which you can edit.

```
def insertNewlines(text, lineLength=int(n)):
    if len(text) <= lineLength:
       return text
    elif text[lineLength] != ' ':
       return insertNewlines(text[:], lineLength + 1)
    else:
       return text[:lineLength] + '<br>' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength + 1:], lineLength)
```

Here, this is just an example of how you may do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for trying, however unfortunatley this yielded an error. I've updated my answer above so my question should be a bit more readable now.

Comment: If the column you need to change is just `df["Messages"]` then, the edited code should work as you expected. If not please share your error.

Comment: Thats it working now, thanks for the help mate. Have a good day.

Comment: Nice, that is, earlier I thought you wanted to loop through all the columns as well. Thanks